# Displaying an outline in the header of a Beamer presentation

Tags: tables, beamer, positioning

I have a number of related frames in a Beamer presentation and I would like to emphasize this relationship by walking through a sort of outline of that part of the presentation. This is what I have so far:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame title}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabular}{ l c c r }
  \textcolor{gray}{Item one...} & \bf{Item two...} & \textcolor{gray}{Item three...} & \textcolor{gray}{Item four...} \\
  \textcolor{gray}{Item five...} & \textcolor{gray}{Item six...} & \textcolor{gray}{Item seven...} & \textcolor{gray}{Item eight..}
\end{tabular}
\end{tiny}

Some content.... perhaps an image, one or two equations, a table...

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have so far]

My plan is to make a copy of the table for each frame and then change which item is bold. The actual table content is wider so it takes up the entire width of the frame. I would like the table to be aligned to the left beneath the frame title. I would like to make it so that the actual content of the frame is not affected. Ideas for how to do this would be much appreciated. If you can solve it without a table that's fine as well of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method works if there is no overlays in the contents of each item. The idea is to collapse all items into one beamer frame and use overlays to highlight the item headings in the frame subtitle.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame title}
\framesubtitle{\footnotesize
  \textbf<1>{item one}\quad
  \textbf<2>{item two}\quad
  \textbf<3>{item three}\quad
  \textbf<4>{item four}\quad
  \textbf<5>{item five}\quad
  \textbf<6>{item six}\quad
}

\only<1>{content for item one}
\only<2>{content for item two}
\only<3>{content for item three}
\only<4>{content for item four}
\only<5>{content for item five}
\only<6>{content for item six}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This is really great, exactly what I was looking for. I tried adding underline as well with `\textunderline<1>{...}` and `\underline<1>{...}` but it didn't work. Do you know how I could make it bold and underlined?

Comment: @Calle: `\underline` is not overlay-aware. In your case, I'd suggest loading `ulem` package in the preamble (`\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`), and redefine the `\uline` command to be overlay aware: `\renewcommand<>{\uline}[1]{\alt#2{\beameroriginal{\uline}{#1}}{#1}}`. Then, you can use `\uline<1>{...}` as you do `\textbf`.